# duplicate key error when using mongodb findandupdate on unique index

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a document if its found else insert it into mongodb. The documents are based on data published through `kafka` so the `findandupdate` function is executed real-time as messages are received. I've already setup a unique index on my collection as shown below

```
db.uniqueTitles.createIndex({title:1},{unique:true})
```

And here is the code which does the `findAndUpdate` on a forked process:

```
    const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
    var {mongoose} = require('../db/titleDb');
    var {createModel} = require('../models/titleModel');
    var titleModel = mongoose.model('uniqueTitles',titleSchema);

    process.on('message', (msg) => {
      var values = JSON.parse(msg.value);
      var bookTitle = new titleModel({
          title:values['book_title'],
          first_seen:values['published_date'],
          last_seen:values['published_date']
        });
      var magazineTitle = new titleModel({
          title:values['magazine_title'],
          first_seen:values['published_date'],
          last_seen:values['published_date']
        });

      titleModel.findOneAndUpdate({title:values['book_title']},{last_seen:values['published_date']},{new:false,upsert:false})
        .then(res=>{
          if (res === null) bookTitle.save().then(res=>{})
        })
        .catch(err => {});

      titleModel.findOneAndUpdate({title:values['magazine_title']},{last_seen:values['published_date']},{new:false,upsert:false})
        .then(res=>{
              if (res === null) magazineTitle.save().then(res=>{})
            })
        .catch(err =>{});
    });
```

But when I execute the program it gives me an error

> ERROR 11000 duplicate key

which I am very confused because this should not be happening. Is this happening because of the potential race conditions caused by the `async` calls by `mongoose`? Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Why are you updating the `titleModel` twice with the same update? Nest your queries.

Comment: sry bout that, I've changed up the code to reflect what I really wanna do, I want to be getting all unique book and magazine titles and when is their first_seen and last_seen time